# Adding list or dictionary in a dictionary with multiple values for one key - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tree, nested

Very first Post here, apologies if it is not proper.
I have 2 Dictionaries with keys and lists as values. I need to assign a list to an element of the list in a dictionary where it matches in other Dictionary 2.

```
Dictionary 1
{'S': ['Close Coupled', 'Wall Hung', 'Btw'], 'E':['Bifold', 'Hinge', 'Sliding', 'Pivot']}

Dictionary 2
{'Close Coupled': ['Close Coupled Contract', 'Close Coupled Open Back', 'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'], 'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless'],'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless'], 'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Sliding': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Pivot': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']} 

Result I am trying to get is.
{'S': {'Close Coupled':['Close Coupled Contract', 'Close Coupled Open Back', 'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'], 'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless'], 'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless'], 'E': 'Bifold':['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Hinge':['700', '800', '900', '1000'],'Sliding':['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Pivot':['700', '800', '900', '1000']}
```

After his I have another dictionary which will be added same way. it is like a Tree structure or nested but I am unable to build up my logic to assign dictionary to each matching element of the list in 1st dictionary.

If it is not clear; please let me know I will try to explain it better.

Thank you

Comment: I tried to solve your problem however I'm not convinced with the expected answer which you wrote. According to you, your output must be a dictionary with only one item where the key is 'S' and value is a dictionary. Could you please check your question and reply to me with some clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have understood your question correctly. However check this code and if it doesn't suit your need kindly let me know.

```
d1= {'S': ['Close Coupled', 'Wall Hung', 'Btw'], 'E':['Bifold', 'Hinge', 'Sliding', 'Pivot']}

d2= {'Close Coupled': ['Close Coupled Contract', 'Close Coupled Open Back', 'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'], 'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless'],'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless'], 'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Sliding': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Pivot': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']}

final_dict= {} # create a dictionary to store the final answer
for item in d1:
    temp= dict() # temporary dictionary
    for i in item d1[item]:
        temp[i]= d2[i]
    final_dict[item]= temp
```

output
print(final_dict)

```
{'E': {'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
  'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
  'Pivot': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
  'Sliding': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']},
 'S': {'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless'],
  'Close Coupled': ['Close Coupled Contract',
   'Close Coupled Open Back',
   'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'],
  'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless']}} `
```

Comment: Thanks. This does the same what I wanted to do. However there is a syntax error in the code " for i in [---item----] d1[item]:" I was doing same thing yesterday but not sure why I was getting hash error for list.

Comment: @Usman Mughal I have modified the code and it's working correctly now. Let me know if any issue exists with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict` comprehension to do this:

```
{keys : {m : d2.get(m) for m in values} for keys, values in d1.items()}


{'S': {'Close Coupled': ['Close Coupled Contract',
   'Close Coupled Open Back',
   'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'],
  'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless'],
  'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless']},
 'E': {'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
  'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
  'Sliding': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
  'Pivot': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']}}
```

DATA:

```
d1 = {'S': ['Close Coupled', 'Wall Hung', 'Btw'], 'E':['Bifold', 'Hinge', 'Sliding', 'Pivot']}
d2 = {'Close Coupled': ['Close Coupled Contract', 'Close Coupled Open Back', 'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'], 'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless'],'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless'], 'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Sliding': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Pivot': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to loop through your first dictionary and get the lists that correspond to the keys of the same name from your second dictionary. For example:

```
d1 = {'S': ['Close Coupled', 'Wall Hung', 'Btw'], 'E':['Bifold', 'Hinge', 'Sliding', 'Pivot']}
d2 = {'Close Coupled': ['Close Coupled Contract', 'Close Coupled Open Back', 'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'], 'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless'],'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless'], 'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Sliding': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'], 'Pivot': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']}
result = dict()

for key, values in d1.items():
    result[key] = dict()
    for value in values:
        result[key][value] = d2[value]

print(result)

# OUTPUT (print does not output indented results shown here for readability only)
# {
#      'S': {
#          'Close Coupled': ['Close Coupled Contract', 'Close Coupled Open Back', 'Close Coupled Open Back Rimless'],
#          'Btw': ['BTW Contract', 'BTW Rimless'],
#          'Wall Hung': ['Wall Hung Contract', 'Wall Hung Rimless']
#          },
#      'E': {
#          'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
#          'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
#          'Sliding': ['700', '800', '900', '1000'],
#          'Pivot': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']
#          }
# }
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well too.. but converts dictionary to list. so not sure if i would be able to do further indexing on it as I need to index further. the Final result should be like S010101 or E010201...
E': [{'Bifold': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']},{'Hinge': ['700', '800', '900', '1000']}]
E [{01:[ 01,02,03,04,05]},{ 02:[01,02,03,04,05]} . .. . so on...

Comment: @UsmanMughal Sorry about that. Edited the answer for the correct output.

Comment: That said, the answer from @Onyambu is a bit more elegant than this one

Comment: @ benvc - prob is what is lists does not have matching keys?

Comment: @UsmanMughal In the current answer, If there is a list item in `d1` without a corresponding key in `d2`, then a dictionary with that item as key and an empty list as value will be added to `result`. If there is a key in `d2` without a corresponding list item in `d1`, then it will be ignored. If there is a specific scenario you are trying to account for, you can edit your question accordingly  (including an example in the dataset) or post another question so we can help.